# Django Updateview - set parameter based on field value or user object

Tags: django

I have a Django UpdateView with a form. In the template I have to show a 'name' value. In case there is customer_id value present in the form, then 'name' is based on that value. If it is empty, then 'name' is based on the user object. 
The 'name' is not saved in the model, so it has to be calculated.

Seems simple, but I cannot get it to work. What I have tried this far:

1. Try to set the value in get_context_data() - not working because get_context_data is called before the form data is bound so I cannot access the customer_id value from the form.
2. Make a method in the form class:

   ```
   def get_name(self):
      if self.is_bound:
           # return name based on form.cleaned_data['customer_id']
      else:
           # return name based on self.user.user_id
   ```

Call the method in the template... but it always returns name based on user. I can see input fields in template with values, but somehow the form is not bound?

I'm not really comfortable with CBV's, but I can't change it to use a FBV. Any ideas how could I accomplish this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems I got it working. You can get the value of the field in get_context_data, if you ask it from a bound field (still weird, since form.is_bound is still False??)

```
company_id = context['form']['company_id'].value()
```

Before, I was doing

```
company_id = context['form'].fields['company_id'].value()
```

..but that was obviously not working.